# What's the meaning of 'plasma' in 'plasma membrane'?

Tags: terminology, cell-membrane, etymology

I wonder why is it called **plasma** membrane - what's the biological meaning of the word 'plasma'?

Comment: Plasma comes from the greek word which means something created or forged

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was a no-brainer, apparently it's more of a historical journey into the origins of Botany. But I have a hypothesis: During the debate of whether the cell or the fluid within it was the origin of life, that fluid was called 'protoplasm' - first formed, i.e. it's the origin of life. The plasma membrane, then, is simply that which surrounds the 'plasma' - the protoplasm.

Comment: If you wanted the etymology of the word, would better have gone to english.stackexchange.com. Also, note that in etymology, there is a large disparity between what hypothesis sounds logical to a layperson and what hypothesis is true.